# How to center a view in a layout without overlapping other view

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

### **The context**

I've got a FrameLayout with two view: an ImageButton and a TextView.

[The base layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZREa.png)

### **What I want :**

- The ImageButton should wrap its content
- The ImageButton is at the left of the layout
- The TextView is at the center of the layout
- The TextView should wrap its content, but not overlapp with the ImageButton, like in this example [Overlapping text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBLi7.png)

### **My first solution**

Use a RelativeLayout to avoid overlapping.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/dialog_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/dialog_close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_padding="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_close"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some text"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/dialog_close"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

But now, the TextView is not centered in the layout: instead it's centered between the ImageButton and the end of the Parent.
[Text not centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VRvl.png)

And I can't add a margin of the size of my button, since I don't really know its size.

### **My second solution**

Keep the RelativeLayout, and add an invisible fake button (same picture as the first one, thus same size). And center the TextView between the two buttons.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/dialog_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/dialog_close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_padding="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_close"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some text"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/dialog_close"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/dialog_margin"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/dialog_margin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_padding="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_close"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Which result in my wanted behavior :
[Result with fake button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/039Ga.png)

But I feel like the use of a fake button is not a correct way to do so.

**Is there another solution to center a view and avoid overlapping than doing that invisible fake button trick?**

I can easily use another kind of layout if it brings a solution (constraint, Linear...)

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: I don't understand how you want it to align exactly but if you want 1 view to be centered and another view to be aligned to that view without overlapping you should be using a `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: @Sander I edit my question to be more clear with the alignment. And don't see how you could do it with ConstraintLayout, but if you have an answer, enlighten me !

Comment: If you want to arrange them horizontally you could enclose them inside `LinearLayout` and then set the attribute of the `layout_gravity="center"` of the textView

Comment: I think you should set a fix size to your ImageView as it can be dangerous to allow any size (you can end with not enough space for the TextView to be displayed, especially on small devices). Like that, you could set a right margin to your TextView as you'd know the size of the ImageView

Comment: @Eselfar: yeah, I didn't think that could be a problem to have a picture with a non fixed size. With that taken into account, it should be easy to center the text !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make the text look centered the margins from both the ends of the parent layout have to be equal. So without adding fake button you can add a margin_right to text equal to width of the button.

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/dialog_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/dialog_close"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_close" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/dialog_close"
        android:layout_marginRight = "//value equal to source width"
        android:text="Some very long text which will overlap my button and I dont want that."
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:gravity="center"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: OP: `And I can't add a margin of the size of my button, since I don't really know its size.`

Comment: check its source you can know the width.

Comment: I will probably go for something like this. It bother me that you can't do it without setting a size to the button and/or the margin, but it's for the moment the better than I can do.Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need the FrameLayout as well. Assuming I understand what you're trying to accomplish you could just use the RelativeLayout as your base layout.

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialog_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/dialog_close"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_close" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialog_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/dialog_close"
            android:text="Some very long text which will overlap my button and I dont want that."
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginEnd="75dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: That was I already did. The problem is that it center the textview between the button and the end of the parent, instead of centering it in the parent

Comment: Are you ok with the empty space after the text? Cause you could use margin_end instead of a button.

Answer (score -1):

Center the `TextView` in the `ConstraintLayout` by wrapping it's content and constraining it to all parent borders by using Constraints. Then center the `ImageButton` vertically by wrapping it's content and constraining it to the top and bottom of the parent. Last you constrain the end of the `ImageButton` to the start of the `TextView`.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialog_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Some text"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/dialog_close"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_padding="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/btn_close"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/dialog_title"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: The Image disappears when the text is too long